# Can the parent process find out the PID of the child process

Tags: python, fork

I have some python code that forks

```
try: 
    pid = os.fork() 
    if pid > 0:
        # parent process, return and keep running
        return
except:
    print("EXCEPTION")
    sys.exit(1)
```

And I would find it useful to be able to know the PID of the child process within the parent process. I am fine with using locks/waits/synchronization methods. I am just trying to be cautious here as I want to make sure I do something safe.

Comment: What do you think the `pid` returned by `os.fork` is?

Comment: I got mixed up! I thought the parent process returned 0 and the child process returned its own PID.

Comment: I also meant to ask this about double fork. Leaving this question up. Making another for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> to be able to know the PID of the child process within the parent process

Actually this is what fork returns to the parent.
This line indicates that you already have it stored in `pid` variable:
`pid = os.fork()`

See the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fork)

> Fork a child process. Return 0 in the child and the child’s process id in the parent. If an error occurs OSError is raised.

and [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fork)

> Upon successful completion, fork() shall return 0 to the child process and shall return the process ID of the child process to the parent process. Both processes shall continue to execute from the fork() function. Otherwise, -1 shall be returned to the parent process, no child process shall be created, and errno shall be set to indicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `pid` returned by `os.fork()` actually is the child's PID for the parent (and zero for the child).

The parent process is handed the child's PID so that it can observe and control the child.

Note that a process can also obtain:

1. Its own PID via `os.getpid()`
2. Its parent's PID via `os.getppid()`